# H5BP Ant Build Script - Event Handler Name Updating

Tags: html5boilerplate

I've read that H5BP Ant Build Script "Updates your HTML to reference [the compiled] hyper-optimized CSS + JS files". Does that include references in the HTML to event handlers whose names have been changed by the minification process?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can accomplish this by exporting the names from the script (as described at https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export) while using the ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS flag.

Answer (score 0):

The Ant Build Script knows nothing about your inline event handlers. It's built with an eye towards the common method of using a library like jQuery to handle your event binding unobtrusively so even if closure compiler offers some export, you would have to adjust the build script yourself to have some task that rewrites the inline event handlers.

Comment: Since the original names can be exported, it isn't necessary to rewrite the handler calls, right?